# { Blog post text alignment in Urdu (Right to Left); }

Tags: html, css, blogs, weebly

Most of my Weebly blog post are in Urdu, but text alignment is coming form left to right which is affecting look of my blog posts. How can i change text alignment from right to left for my blog page?

Thanks and Regards,

umer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `direction: rtl` on your paragraphs and headings.

```
p {
    direction: rtl;
}
```